# goamz/sqs/md5.go:57: undefined: md5.Sum issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-sqs

I am trying to manipulate aws sqs on a http://www.nitrous.io box with golang version go1.1.1 linux/amd64.

When I import the sqs module from this github repository https://github.com/crowdmob/goamz/tree/master/sqs  and I run my code with a

```
 go run myCode.go
```

I face this issue:

```
# github.com/crowdmob/goamz/sqs                                                                                                       
../src/github.com/crowdmob/goamz/sqs/md5.go:57: undefined: md5.Sum
```

My call for that module is like this:

```
import "github.com/crowdmob/goamz/sqs"
```

And I can use other modules from the same repo. for example the aws and the S3 one

```
import "github.com/crowdmob/goamz/aws"
import "github.com/crowdmob/goamz/s3"
```

Looking at the error in the /sqs/md5.go from the goamz repository I can see the function Sum and it seems the import are done well:

```
package sqs

import (
    "crypto/md5"
    "encoding/binary"
    "sort"
)
```

So I am a bit clueless on what's happening. Any Idea?

Comment: This probably not the reason but the state of that project is "build error"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using an old version of Go -- `md5.Sum` didn't exist in go1.1.1.

Update to go1.3

Comment: Exact, that was it, old version of go. Tks @JimB. My "go box" on http:www.nitrous.io was created some time ago before the go 1.3 and the go package was not updated. I had to actually re install it via their autopart mechanism.

Answer (score -1):

Did you performed the testing files ? It could come from this, refering to the build state as said  chendesheng